# Interpolation and data binding doesn't change

Tags: angular6, interpolation

I have an angular project where I use interpolation and data binding.
Throughout the project there is only one component in which it does not work.

I have a simple variable named **title**, in which if I write something during the **ngOnInit** method, it is correctly displayed in the html.

However, if I change the value of that variable at a later time, the html is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
toLeave : boolean = undefined;
title = '';

ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'Review';
    this.router.events.pipe(
       filter((event: NavigationEnd) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
     ).subscribe(res => {
          if(this.toLeave != undefined)
             return;
          if(res.url.indexOf('toLeave') >= 0){
              this.toLeave = true;
              this.title = 'Review to leave';
           }else{
              this.toLeave = false;
              this.title = 'Review received';
           }
      })
  }
```

And in my HTML:

```
<span>{{title}}</span>
```

And i try also this:

```
<span [innerHTML]="title"></span>
```

The end result is that in the html "Review" is visible.
What is done in the subscribe is therefore not detected.

I tried to force the detection of the change with **ChangeDetectorRef**, but when I go to call the **detectChanges** method, the object is already destroyed.

I then tried with **ApplicationRef** using the **tick** method, but it does not change anything.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: so you are trying to update the title after the component has been destroyed due to a navigation change? i guess that just won't work because angular "gave up" on that component the second the navigation triggered. no more view updates will be done after that. at least if i understand you correctly.

Comment: not exactly, I'm using the same component for 2 pages with 2 different routes, so when loading the component, I check on which url was used to define some small different behaviors, as for example in this case I change the title.

When I go to set the title the component has just been created, and it should not be destroyed.

Comment: where are you setting the value of "toLeave"? what is its value when the router event triggers? i guess we need some more code here in order to be able to help

Comment: in the end I figured out the problem.
all the code I have moved into the constructor, and in that context it works correctly, even if I do not explain why.

Thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solveld the problem.

There was one simple thing I had not tried to do.

I moved the code from inside **ngOnInit** and I run it inside the constructor.
Everything works correctly right now